# how to passing validation laravel controller to sweet alert swal

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, sweetalert

I first tried sweet alert here. I want to create a data input eror validation list displayed in sweet alert, first I tried not to fill all textfields so the result would be a list of anything that misinput or not filling in on textfield and being sampled in sweet alert. I've tried but only get last his value is just a list of unbending data, please help me

controller

```
 public function simpanpegawai(Request $req)
    {
        $messages = [
            'nama.required' => 'Field Nama Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'nama.min' => 'Field nama tidak boleh kurang dari 5 kata',
            'nama.regex' => 'Field nama tidak boleh angka',
            'alamat.required' => 'Field Alamat Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'alamat.min' => 'Field alamat tidak boleh 5 kata',
            'tempat_lahir.required' => 'Field tempat lahir harus diisi !',
            'tempat_lahir.regex' => 'field Tempat lahir tidak boleh ada angka',
            'tgl_lahir.required' => 'Field Tanggal Lahir harus diisi !',
            'tgl_lahir.date' => 'Field Tanggal Lahir harus format tanggal!',
            'pendidikan_terkahir.not_in' => 'Field pendidikan terkahir Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'no_telp.required' => 'Field no telpon Gak Boleh Kosong',
            'no_telp.min' => 'Field no telpon Harus minimal 10 ',
            'jkel.not_in' => 'Field jenis kelamin harus diisi !',
            'id_jabatan.not_in' => 'Field jabatan harus diisi !',
            'status.not_in' => 'Field status harus diisi !',
            ];

        $validator = \Validator::make($req->all(), [
            'nama' => 'required|min:5|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/',
            'alamat' => 'required|min:5',
            'no_telp' => 'required|min:10',
            'tempat_lahir' => 'required|min:5|regex:/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/',
            'tgl_lahir' => 'required|date',
            'pendidikan_terkahir' => 'not_in:0',
            'jkel' => 'not_in:0',
            'id_jabatan' => 'not_in:0',
            'status' => 'not_in:0',
        ], $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
        } else {
            $user = new \App\User;
            $user->name = $req->nama;
            $user->role = $req->id_jabatan;
            $user->username = $req->nama;
            $user->password = bcrypt($req->no_telp);
            $simpan = $user->save();


            $req->request->add(['user_id' => $user->id]);
            $pegawai = \App\PegawaiModel::create($req->all());
            if ($simpan == 1) {

                $status = "Tersimpan";

            } else {
                $status = "Gagal";
            }
            echo json_encode(array("status" => $status));
        }
    }
```

sweet alert in blade script

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#formpegawai').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.errors) {

                        jQuery.each(data.errors, function (key, value) {
                            swal({
                                title: "Pesan Eror",
                                text: value,
                                timer: 5000,
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                type: "error"
                            })
                        });

                    } else {
                        swal({
                            text: data.status,
                            timer: 5000,
                            icon:"success",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            type: "error"
                        })
                        $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {

                }
            });
```

picture
[image]

Comment: what is the error then ?

Comment: the error i  got just last message of validation like picture,validation message should have given up everything because I didn't input all textfield

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically because your sweetalert is inside in your foor each, now the value is overwrite everytime the loop increments. To solve this please move your sweet alert after your loop

```
if(data.errors) {
    var values = '';
    jQuery.each(data.errors, function (key, value) {
         values += value
    });

    swal({
        title: "Pesan Eror",
        text: values,
        timer: 5000,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        type: "error"
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, this has appeared the list error, but how do I smooth out the list writings?

Comment: what do you mean of smooth ?

Comment: sry im using google translate , i mean alignment the text  
because his result is untidy

Comment: what kind of alignment ? Like each error is one row ?

Comment: yeah like that each eror in one row

Comment: you have to use content: wrapper in your swal alert I think, I'm not expert with that alert I just answered your issue why it goes like that

Answer (score 0):

In you controller after giving the validation rules, try this:

```
     if ($validator->fails()) {

       Alert::error('Error', $validator->messages()->all()[0]);
       return redirect()->back();

    }
```

it returns the earliest encountered error from validation rules defined.